# How to change UITableViewCell edit button background color?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

When UItableview in edit mode, if I set custom color for cell. Then delete button background color is not match my custom cell's background color.

So I want change delete button's background color white -> black.

How can I do this??

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @IBAction func deleteCell(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.tableView.isEditing == true {
            self.tableView.isEditing = false
        } else {
            self.tableView.isEditing = true
        }
    }

Comment: @VishalPethani here is my code

Comment: @usinuniverse Please update your original question with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following solution

On `awakeFromNib()` method of your subclass `UITableViewCell`:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `IBAction` for deleteCell

Try following solution

Add following **Delegate** method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexPath) in 
        // edit item at indexpath
     }

        edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    return [edit, delete]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I already know swipe delete. I want edit mode like my screenshot.

Comment: That's not it. What I want to do is to enable the EDIT mode when I press the button connected to the IBOUTLET, like the picture. I do not want to use swipe.